# ios 8 UISearchResultsTableView Crash

Tags: crash, ios8

```
CRASH: An instance 0x7996e000 of class UISearchResultsTableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x78fcb720> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x78febe10: Observer: 0x0, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x78ff2280>
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x78ffbe10: Observer: 0x0, Key path: contentSize, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x78fc2dd0>
```

Those above are bug info from my console.
It could reappear constantly only on **ios8**, while **ios7** runs well. There is no KVO added in my code, nor did I use Autolayout. Basically, I click the searchbar, input some chars and click cancel after the result table appears, then, when I click back button to previous view, it crashes.

Could anyone please help me here?
Thanks in advance!